# Why D3.js does not display anything ? (RoR application)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, d3.js

I am learning D3.js in order to replace Highcharts in my application, so it can be released under GPL license. I must be missing something really stupid, because I can't get it to display the least element, but text.

First, displaying D3 text works fine. Here is the end of my page:

```
        ...
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="progression">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="impact">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  <!-- End of page -->
        
  <script>
      
      // Drawing progression
      d3.select("#progression").append("p").text("Progression");
      // Drawing impact
      d3.select("#impact").append("p").text("Impact");
  
  </script>
```

It correctly displays the words Progression and Impact where expected.

Now I try to draw an axis, based on the example from [Intro do D3.js](https://square.github.io/intro-to-d3/parts-of-a-graph/)

```
        ...
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="progression">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="impact">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  <!-- End of tab content -->
  
  <script>
      
      // Drawing progression
      var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0,10])
      .range([0,200]);
  
      var xAxis = d3.axisTop(x)
      .ticks(10);
      
      var graph =  d3.select('#progression')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 300)
      .attr('height', 150);
      
      graph.append('g')           
      .attr('class', 'x axis')   
      .call(xAxis); 
     
      // Drawing impact
      d3.select("#impact").append("p").text("Impact");
  
  </script>
```

In this case, nothing is created in the DIVs, even the word Impact is not displayed any more.

What do I do wrong ?
Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In D3,

> regardless of orientation, axes are always rendered at the origin.

In an SVG, the origin (0,0) is at the top left corner.

So, you have to translate it down:

```
graph.append('g') 
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,130)")
```

Here is a demo with your code:

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="progression">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="impact">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of tab content -->

<script>
    // Drawing progression
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 10])
        .range([0, 200]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisTop(x)
        .ticks(10);

    var graph = d3.select('#progression')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', 300)
        .attr('height', 150);

    graph.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,130)")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Drawing impact
    d3.select("#impact").append("p").text("Impact");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. What unlocked the situation is this : <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>. Why do I ever need to add this since the d3_rails gem is correctly installed ?

Comment: I don't use Ruby, but here in the S.O. snippet I had to reference the D3 library in order to use it.